# Passing data from one controller to another in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, mean

I'm trying to pass some data from a selectbox from one controller to another page with different controller in Angular, but I can't seem to get it working. Could some one help me with this?

This is the selectbox with the DataCtrl:

```
<div class="searchbox" ng-controller="DataCtrl">
  <div class="plumber-by-city col-sm-12 home-text-col">
   <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="change()" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

On change I am taking the value from the selectbox and placing it into $rootScope:

```
$scope.change = function() {
  $scope.type = $routeParams.type;
    console.log($scope.type);
  $rootScope = $scope.selectedItem.city;
    console.log($rootScope);
};
```

In the second controller I am trying to get the data from $rootScope and use it there but is not working

```
app.controller('DataCtrl2', function($rootScope,$scope,$http) {
  $scope.selectedItem.city = $rootScope.selectedItem.city;
  console.log($rootScope.selectedItem.city);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: avoid `$rootScope`, use `service\factory` instead.